# Why does the LTE Specification define SC-FDMA as the modulation scheme for the reverse link?

Tags: electrical-engineering, telecommunication, lte, modulation

The LTE specification specifies SC-FDMA as the encoding scheme for the reverse link (mobile to base station) when the forward link uses OFDMA.

What is the reason for the difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SC-FDMA is encoded and transmitted from the handset where there are power tradeoffs.  This encoding is better than OFDMA for the handset for the following related reasons:

- Reduces peak to average power ratio
- Increases efficiency of the power amplifier
- Increases battery life

So at the base station they can employ transmitters that can handle a higher peak transmit power, with lower efficiency as it has a significant amount of power available.  But on a mobile handset, this requires more expensive components, more space, and, probably most importantly, more power since peak transmissions are not as efficient as transmitting at a lower level but for a longer period of time (ie, higher peak to average ratio means lower energy efficiency, more heat, more power). The tradeoff is a little lower spectrum efficiency, but it's worth it for increased battery life, and particularly since most high speed data is going to the handset, not coming from it.

[This short video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dr4YQAfifKA) explains further.